# How to create functions in python such that they return x as a variable? (interpolation)

Tags: python, interpolation, numerical-methods

How to create a functinon in Python such that for example:

```
n = int(input("number of knots: "))

xsolmed=[]

for i in range(n+1):
    xsolmed.append(-1+(2*i/n))

def x(x):
    return x
lni=[]
formula=1

for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(n+1):
        if i==j:
            pass
        formula = (x(x)-xsolmed[i])/(xsolmed[j]-xsolmed[i])*formula
```

I think I need it to return the function such that the formula variable is a function by x in its own right and so later i can call upon it in the fashion

```
formula(10)=output
```

Comment: formula(10)=output

there is something known as L value and R value

Comment: formula(10) is instance of a function and hence only has a value not a variable name to assign to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the results of a function call equal to your desired variable.

```py
def f(x):
    "A function that changes nothing"
    return x

a = f(5) # same as a = 5
```

To avoid confusion, I recommend that you don't give functions the same name as their arguments, (i.e., don't do `def x(x): ...`).

If you want `formula` to be a function, then declare it as one, after which the correct syntax would be `output = formula(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

formula(10) is instance of a function and hence only has a value not a variable name to assign to.

A good way to write above code will be:

```
n = int(input("number of knots: "))

xsolmed=[]

for i in range(n+1):
    xsolmed.append(-1+(2*i/n))

def y(x):
    return x

def formula_calc(X):
    formula=1

    for i in range(n+1):
        for j in range(n+1):
            if i==j:
                pass
            formula = (X-xsolmed[i])/(xsolmed[j]-xsolmed[i])*formula

    return formula

# now formula is a function of x. X can itself be a function.
print(formula(y(7))
# this will print value of formula at 7 as x(7) is 7.
```

Comment: I am aware of that. I would like to amend my code such that it could function in such a fashion.